# Pull last 3 elements from a DataFrame as an array of numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame where the columns are open, high, low, close, volume (stock data). And the rows are the last 10 trading days (stock symbol & date)

I need to get the most recent three close values in an array. And I'm sure this can be done, but I can't figure out how. I know the values are history.close[-1], history.close[-2], history.close[-3].

How do I pull this end slice as an array of numbers?

Comment: `history.iloc[-3:, -2]` if there is only one stock but I think you have more than 1. Can you post your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a negative array index and slice notation.  This is one of the really nice features of python:

```
tail = history.close[-3:]
```

or, if you need them as a numpy array:

```
tail_arr = history.close.values[-3:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do

```
history["close"].tail(3).to_array()
```